# Method to get a value is returning an object as disposed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following:

This is in a common library:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Attribute> GetImageDimensions(int mediaCategory, int platformId, AttributeType typeOfImage)
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var settingLanguage = typeOfImage.ToString();

            var attr = db.MediaCategoryImageDimensions.Where(
                id =>
                id.MediaCategoryId == mediaCategory &&
                id.PlatformId == platformId &&
                id.Attribute.Setting == settingLanguage).Select(dim => dim.Attribute).Include(s => s.Value);
            return attr;
        } 
    }
```

With the following call in another project:

```
 var expectedDimension = AttributeDAO.GetImageDimensions(
                                MediaCategoryDAO.GetMediaCategoryId(_objectToValidate.MediaCategory),
                                _airline.AirlinePlatforms.First().PlatformId,
                                AttributeType.RecommendedPreviewDimension);
```

My problem is that every time, I get a return value saying that the results of the enumeration is that the object has be disposed.

I have also tried moving the attr variable outside the scope of the using thinking that that was the problem.

I am struggling to understand why my return value is this exception:

> "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Comment: The context is disposed prior to this operation. What type of the application do you have?

Comment: I tend to wrap the access of the DataContent inside a Unit of Work using the Repository pattern. You can also keep the Entities object around as a member of the class so it is not in a disposed state. You will need to manage its life-cycle by eventually calling Dispose on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are returning a `Linq` expression, the query will happen after the context is disposed ([deferred](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) execution)

You either need to remove the using statement and only dispose of the context after you have extracted all info from it or you need to return the results from the query before you exit the method.

You could call `return attr.ToList()` on the return to force the execution but that may have negative impacts on performance as we cannot see what you are doing the results but since you are filtering results within this is probably your best option.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Is there a better way to do this? A different call that will return an unconnected object to my context?

Answer (score 2):

Call ToList() on the attr object prior to returning it. That will enumerate the list.

```
var attr = db.MediaCategoryImageDimensions.Where(
            id =>
            id.MediaCategoryId == mediaCategory &&
            id.PlatformId == platformId &&
            id.Attribute.Setting == settingLanguage).Select(dim => dim.Attribute).Include(s => s.Value).ToList();
```